# Use .Select().Join() to Join Two DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I have been searching high and low for this to no avail.  I have two DataTables that I want to join *without* creating a new resultant table as I simply need to update some rows in one of the tables to be displayed in a grid view, similar to the below code, but with a join:

```
sage_invoices.Select("CCE2 IS NULL")
                .ToList<DataRow>()
                .ForEach(row =>
                {
                    row["Error"] = 1;
                    row["ErrorMessage"] = "Missing Region Code (Dimension 2 - CCE2)";
                });
```

Everything I've found produces a new output datatable, similar to the below code:

```
var collection = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
         join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
         on t1["id"] equals t2["id"]
         select new { T1 = t1, T2 = t2 };
```

What I can't find is how to join two DataTables using .Join:

```
sage_invoices.Select()
                .Join(<What Goes here?>)
                .ToList<DataRow>()
                .ForEach(row =>
                {
                    row["Error"] = 1;
                    row["ErrorMessage"] = "ITMREF is not a Sage Product Code";
                });
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.

Thanks
Gareth

Comment: Help in VS is no good either as it sends you here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/bb344797(v=vs.105)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically accomplish this by building an anonymous object that contains a reference to my source and destination objects through a Join or GroupJoin, then looping over the result of the Join to update my destination object. See the example below.

Take a look at the documentation on [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535047(v=vs.110).aspx). Join is great for a 1-1 match, while GroupJoin is a 0-* match (like a SQL left join). The arguments to Join and GroupJoin allow you to specify a selector function for each IEnumerable followed by a selector function for the output object. Note that `t1` and `t2` below refer to `table1` and `table2`.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var table1 = GetEmptyTable();
        table1.Rows.Add(1, "Old Value", false);
        table1.Rows.Add(2, "Untouched Value", false);

        var table2 = GetEmptyTable();
        table2.Rows.Add(1, "New Value", false);
        table2.Rows.Add(3, "Unused Value", false);

        Console.WriteLine("Before...");
        Console.WriteLine(PrintTable(table1));

        var matched = table1.Select()
            .Join(table2.Select(), t1 => (int)t1["A"], t2 => (int)t2["A"], (t1, t2) 
=> new
            {
                DestinationRow = t1,
                SourceRow = t2
            });
        foreach (var match in matched)
        {
            match.DestinationRow["B"] = match.SourceRow["B"];
            match.DestinationRow["C"] = true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After...");
        Console.WriteLine(PrintTable(table1));
    }

    private static DataTable GetEmptyTable()
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("C", typeof(bool));
        return table;
    }

    private static string PrintTable(DataTable table)
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, table.Select().Select(x => "[" + 
string.Join(", ", x.ItemArray) + "]"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, think I'm getting my head around it.  I have the below code now, but it's not returning anything even though I know it should (tested in MSSQL).  One row in "src" has ITMREF with a value of 10 while a row in "lookup" has a BillingCode with a value of 10.  Both of these columns are varchar / string.      var error_rows = sage_invoices.Select()
                     .Join(sage_billing_conversion.Select(), src => sage_invoices.Columns["ITMREF"], lookup => sage_billing_conversion.Columns["BillingCode"], (src, lookup) => new { DestinationRow = src, SourceRow = lookup });

Comment: It looks like your key selector functions are using `sage_invoices` and `sage_billing_conversion` when they should be using `src` and `lookup`. `src` and `lookup` are the individual `DataRow` instances, so you are essentially providing a mapping function to retrieve a key value for each `DataRow`. `sage_invoices.Columns` and `sage_billing_conversion.Columns` is returning a `DataColumn` instance (not the actual value), which will never match between those two tables.

Comment: Oh man... I clearly need coffee.  Thanks Tyler - that got it.  You're a legend!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.